# "figure options" sticks to "edit axis" toolbar

Tags: matplotlib

When opening the "edit axis" toolbar inside the figure, a "figure options" window opens. This window "sticks" to the figure behind and blocks it. When moved, it takes the figure with it and so when editing the axes, I can not see the results update without closing it which makes it hard to iterate with different scales etc. This was not in previous versions of matplotlib. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Again, exact steps for reproduction are needed. Which versions of which relevant libraries are in use? In which previous version did that not happen?

Comment: I'm using spyder 3.2.8 on ubuntu, matplotlib version 2.2.2 and ploting a standard plot (matplotlib.pyplot.plot(...) ). This was not happening when I was using spyder 3.1.3 but I'm not sure about the matplotlib version. I was also on windows then.   Another thing - next to the "edit axis" toolbar is the "configure subplot" toolbar and it does not "stick" to the figure when opened.

Comment: I do think this is a matplotlib thing, not related to spyder. I suspect you use the Qt5Agg backend? I doubt there can be done anything to it from the outside. But if you are correct and it did work differently in a previous version it would really help to know which version that was to find out what exactly changed and if it can be reverted.

Comment: I use "Automatic" backend, but this also happens with Qt5 (perhaps that's also the automatic choice)